# Implement markers in webkit scroll bars?

Tags: javascript, css, html, webkit

I'd like to implement markers in Webkit scrollbars, so that I can visually indicate where certain portion of text is located in larger document.

I have styled my scroll bars with `-webkit-*` CSS rules, but I am not sure if I can go beyond that and modify looks of `track` object.

Does anyone have an idea about how to tackle it?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this (just an example of an applied style)

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Nope, I rather look for something like this: `https://github.com/sj26/jquery.scrollmarkers` but with markers being rendered inside scrollbars